# Language subfolder with TranslatePress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, timber

I added Translatepress and Timber into my Wordpress to test out the translation/Multilanguage capabilities. However, Translatepress tries to load `http://example.com/en` which results in a 404.

Any idea how Elementor and other themes are able to accommodate `/en` without running into a 404?
More importantly, can we get Timber to do the same?

Thank you.

Comment: may be obviuos but have you refreshed your permalinks? Timber should not effect your url structure

Comment: I just refreshed, doesn't work. `http://example.com/en` still results in 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below to check what permalink settings you are using and how to update, as this can cause issues with different lanugage versions.

1. Go to your WordPress admin, in Settings > Permalinks
2. Select anything but  NOT the first choice ("plain") and make sure you don't have /index.php in your URLs, or using a custom permalink structure.
3. Save your changes
4. Refresh your web page and it should be working

If the problem is not solved, check if the “mod_rewrite” module is enabled on your website. If not, you would need to enable it.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. But it was Custom Structure `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` by default which did not work as well. Could you make that more specific in your post before I mark it as the answer? Thanks!